# Detect that URL has been changed by ui-router, not by user?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, logic

I have a SPA angularjs application and have tabs within the application. Every click on the tab has different URL. But every time the URL changes, the page has to do something. I have to separate the user behavior and application behavior. Because every click on each tab, changes the URL and each time I update URL from application it changes. How do I know that the application changed the URL and not user manually?

If further explanations are required- please tell me.

Comment: Can you explicit what you expect from a user tab click and what is changing  in the page, in the tabs, etc. Also it is not clear why you want to know what updated the url.

Comment: Not at all clear what the difference would be or even why it would matter how the url got changed. Provide a [mcve]. Sounds like an incorrect implementation approach of tabs to me

Comment: How clicking on a tab changes URL? You can, for example, bind it to some ng-click and before changing the URL - mark that this is an user-action. 
Not best solution and it may get complicated, better to understand the general problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @BenBracha change it within the browser URL it self. The change from the application is made by `$state.go`

Comment: @charlietfl might be, I didn't implemented it.